# Ember 2.0 upgrade telling me that there is an application view when there is none

Tags: ember.js

When I updated ember to 2.0.0 it is now complaining about the following View.  The thing is that there is no view.js file for the application route in my code.  How do I get around this?

```
define('my-app/views/application', ['exports', 'ember'], function (exports, Ember) {

    'use strict';

    exports['default'] = Ember['default'].View.extend({});

});
```

Stacktrace:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of
>   undefined(anonymous function) @ application.js:5mod.state @
>   loader.js:141tryFinally @ loader.js:22requireModule @
>   loader.js:139Ember.DefaultResolver.extend._extractDefaultExport @
>   ember-resolver.js:390resolveOther @ ember-resolver.js:122superWrapper
>   @
>   ember.debug.js:21068exports.default._emberRuntimeSystemObject.default.extend.resolveView
>   @
>   ember.debug.js:4891exports.default._emberRuntimeSystemObject.default.extend.resolve
>   @ ember.debug.js:4749resolve @ ember.debug.js:4486resolve @
>   ember.debug.js:2152Registry.resolve @ ember.debug.js:1720factoryFor @
>   ember.debug.js:1370Container.lookupFactory @
>   ember.debug.js:1285initialize @ key-responder.js:36(anonymous
>   function) @ ember.debug.js:4168(anonymous function) @
>   ember.debug.js:4184visit @ ember.debug.js:2194DAG.topsort @
>   ember.debug.js:2305_emberRuntimeSystemNamespace.default.extend._runInitializer
>   @
>   ember.debug.js:4183_emberRuntimeSystemNamespace.default.extend.runInstanceInitializers
>   @
>   ember.debug.js:4166_emberRuntimeSystemNamespace.default.extend.didBecomeReady
>   @ ember.debug.js:4198Queue.invoke @ ember.debug.js:978Queue.flush @
>   ember.debug.js:1042DeferredActionQueues.flush @
>   ember.debug.js:838Backburner.end @ ember.debug.js:166Backburner.run @
>   ember.debug.js:288Backburner.join @ ember.debug.js:323run.join @
>   ember.debug.js:19078(anonymous function) @ ember.debug.js:19141fire @
>   jquery.js:3099self.fireWith @ jquery.js:3211jQuery.extend.ready @
>   jquery.js:3417completed @ jquery.js:3433

### UPDATE

A very weird thing, I added a `pods/application/view.js` file with the following content.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend();
```

An now ember seems to be using this instead of creating an `Ember.View` for me.

Answer (score 0):

The compiled output looks like you have a file in `app/views/application.js` containing:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.View.extend({});
```

Your pod view/component workaround overrides this file, but neither should be present in an Ember 2.x app (unless you're using ember-legacy-views). The best solution would be to delete both files.

Comment: The weird thing is that both files don't exist - somehow - maybe through an addon or something it thinks there is one.